# Java Problemas para obtener color de fuente en celda de Excel xlsx

Tags: java, excel, color

Tengo el siguiente Excel:

[[image: Excel1]

Usando Java, quiero recuperar el **color de fuente** presente en **cada celda**. Necesito solo el texto y el color de fuente. El **estilo**, **tamaño** y **color de fondo** **no son necesarios** para mí. Tened en cuenta que la celda **A5** tiene **2 palabras con colores distintos**, así que para esa celda necesitaría recuperar 2 colores.

Lo he intentado usando el **API de POI**, pero no soy capaz de hacer funcionar mi algoritmo para todos los casos. Este es el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Desktop\\example.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Row row = itr.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                    System.out.println(
                            "<<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: " + ((XSSFFont) ((XSSFCellStyle) cell.getCellStyle()).getFont())
                                    .getXSSFColor().getARGBHex());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                    break;
                default:
                }
            }
            
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

El código es simple:

1. Obtener el fichero Excel
2. Recuperar la hoja
3. Iterar sobre las celdas
4. Print del contenido de la celda e intentar obtener el color con [XSSCellStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html)

Pero la salida no es la que esperaba:

```
hello           <<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: FF000000
hello           <<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: FFFF0000
hello           <<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: FF70AD47
hello           <<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: FFCE88D0
hello world         <<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: FF000000
hello           <<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: FF000000
```

1. Para los casos 1, 2, 3, 4 y 6 la salida es **OK** porque se informa del color correcto
2. Para el caso 5, **no está OK** porque si hay **2 o más palabras con diferente color**, devuelve **000000**, o lo que es lo mismo, **NEGRO**.

Necesitaría que el último caso devolviera algo como esto:

```
hello <<<<<<<COLOR: FFEBCB46  world <<<<<<<<<<COLOR: FF70AD47
```

Pero no sé cómo obtener el color de varias palabras dentro de una celda.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto? ¿Es imposible? ¿Debería usar otra API?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. BUena pregunta. ¿Qué versión de POI estás usando?

Comment: Hola!! 3.17, pero he probado con versiones más recientes sin éxito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Lo primero:

esa versión tiene varias vulnerabilidades graves y no deberías usarla en entornos productivos.

#### El problema

Adaptando un poco tu código a a la versión 5

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("/home/pepito/Downloads/testfile.xlsx");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            for (Row row : sheet) {
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case STRING:
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                            System.out.println(
                                    "<<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: " + ((XSSFCellStyle) cell.getCellStyle()).getFont()
                                            .getXSSFColor().getARGBHex());
                            break;
                        case NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                            break;
                        default:
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Usé un archivo con este contenido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si le haces debug al contenido de `cell.getRichStringCellValue()`, puedes ver en `st` (o haciendo `cell.getRichStringCellValue().getCTRst()`):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que esa celda está representada más o menos así

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <main:r>
    <main:rPr>
      <main:sz val="11"/>
      <main:color rgb="FFC9211E"/>
      <main:rFont val="Calibri"/>
      <main:family val="2"/>
      <main:charset val="1"/>
    </main:rPr>
    <main:t xml:space="preserve">Modify "screen"</main:t>
  </main:r>
  <main:r>
    <main:rPr>
      <main:sz val="11"/>
      <main:color rgb="FF000000"/>
      <main:rFont val="Calibri"/>
      <main:family val="2"/>
      <main:charset val="1"/>
    </main:rPr>
    <main:t xml:space="preserve"> something something </main:t>
  </main:r>
  <main:r>
    <main:rPr>
      <main:sz val="11"/>
      <main:color rgb="FF3FAF46"/>
      <main:rFont val="Calibri"/>
      <main:family val="2"/>
      <main:charset val="1"/>
    </main:rPr>
    <main:t xml:space="preserve">option selection</main:t>
  </main:r>
  <main:r>
    <main:rPr>
      <main:sz val="11"/>
      <main:color rgb="FF000000"/>
      <main:rFont val="Calibri"/>
      <main:family val="2"/>
      <main:charset val="1"/>
    </main:rPr>
    <main:t xml:space="preserve"> so everything works!</main:t>
  </main:r>
</xml-fragment>
```

Peeero si haces `getFont().getXSSFColor()`, sólo va a traer `FFC9211E`. Como ves, pareciera que toma el primer bloque main que hay dentro del contenido de la celda.

#### Qué opciones hay?

1. Hacer `String richTextString = font.((XSSFColor) ((XSSFFont)cell.getRichStringCellValue().getFontAtIndex(i)) .getXSSFColor()).getARGBHex()` y recorrer carácter a carácter para ver qué estilo tiene aplicado cada uno

```
for (int i = 0; i < richTextString.length(); i++) {
    String nextColor = font.((XSSFColor) ((XSSFFont)cell.getRichStringCellValue().getFontAtIndex(i))
        .getXSSFColor()).getARGBHex();
...
```

Eso va a dar el hex del color para el estilo por cada carácter, tendrías que ir viendo cuándo cambia e irlo añadiendo a una lista o arreglo o set o alguna estructura que desees

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <main:color rgb="FF000000"/>
  <main:sz val="11.0"/>
  <main:name val="Calibri"/>
  <main:family val="2"/>
  <main:charset val="1"/>
</xml-fragment>
```

En el richString se aplican unos `FormatRun`, que son los que van poniendo "capas" de estilo. Puedes averiguarlos con

`cell.getRichStringCellValue().numFormattingRuns()`

Que en mi celda de prueba da 4. Si después hacemos

```
int pepe1 = cell.getRichStringCellValue().numFormattingRuns();
for (int i = 0; i < pepe1; i++){
    System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getIndexOfFormattingRun(i) + "\t\t\t");
}
```

Ahí salen los índices con los carácteres donde cambia el estilo aplicado y sólo necesitas usar estos valores en getFontAtIndex.

`0          15          36          52`

2. Parsear el richString e ir identificando cada main dentro del fragmento. Odio esta opción porque hay que lidiar con el namespace y con cosas aburridas de OOXML y la implementación de MS, etc etc etc

Comment: Sin lugar a dudas, el mejor análisis del problema que me han dado hoy. Imaginaba que algo de esto iba a tener que hacer lamentablemente, pero te has tomado las molestias de debuggear y has dado con la tecla. La opción 2 me parece más acertada y eficiente en tiempos. Programaré una pieza que encaje con lo que necesito. Muchas gracias!! Marco respuesta como válida!

Comment: @ls_52 Estuve buscando cómo vincular los estilos del stylesheet del documento con el richString al leerlo, pero desafortunadamente no me dio el tiempo para mirar. _Tal vez_ con algo más de tiempo uno pueda hacer eso (de algún lado saca la info ese método getFontAtIndex...

Comment: No te preocupes, con lo que me has comentado, creo que tengo lo necesario para continuar. Esta info al final la tengo que llevar a un Word, pero respetando los colores y no sabía cómo conseguirlo. Esto lo soluciona todo, así que sin problema :)

Comment: Respecto a lo de las vulnerabilidades, era consciente de ello, pero esto no iba a estar en ningún entorno productivo por lo que no habría problema. Tampoco me cuesta migrar lo hecho a POI 5, así que podría hacerlo ya que tengo que rehacer varias cosas. Gracias!

Comment: @ls_52 edité la respuesta añadiendo algo más de pistas sobre cómo recorrer ese richString. La clave son esos FormatRun viendo [el código fuente](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRichTextString.java?revision=1890120&view=markup).